# Authentication token expired email from Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, security-token

I have noticed periodically I receive an email notification stating

> A Marketing Cloud Connect authentication token expired for this Marketing Cloud business unit and Salesforce org.

When I log into the related MC org, the token status is current. Any ideas why this might occur?

I have noticed sometimes when logging in as the connected user account in SFDC it triggers this email, not sure why.. the token is still active and no passwords were reset.

Comment: I get those every day, sent from random user names - after opening a support case, they said that this is a know issue, but provided no fix so far.

Comment: Is there a known bug report that I can reference?

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: With the october release they have moved to JWT as opposed to tokens, You have to enable TSE to take advantage of this better auth method:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_mcc_jwt_compatibility.htm&type=5  Upgrading to this auth method should put a stop to these emails and the issue

Comment: @EazyE I haven't got this enabled yet, if I turn this on and reconnect the accounts will it lose all my existing sync'd objects?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your Marketing Cloud Connector, you’ll need to use a [Secure Salesforce API User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331470&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1) on the CRM side.

Likewise on the Marketing Cloud side, the [Tracking User](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_si_tracking_user.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) will need to have Administrator and Marketing Cloud Administrator acres with API Enabled. Make sure you click into the user and click the “Integrate” link where it says **Salesforce.com Status**.

Lastly, you may need to clear out the user mappings and OAuth tokens by following the steps below:

Proceed with the following steps to clear OAuth tokens:

1. Log in to Salesforce using an incognito (private) browser session.
2. Select your Username in the upper right-hand corner, then select Developer Console.
3. Click Debug, then select Execute anonymous window
4. Execute the following Code, each line separately:

   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('Id_of_System_User');
   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('Id_of_System_User|Parent_BU_MID');
   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('Id_of_System_User|Default_BU_MID'); 
   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER');
   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|Parent_BU_MID');
   et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|Default_BU_MID');

Note: Replace the Id_of_System_User in the code above with the Salesforce ID of your system user; replace MID with MID of the integrated Business Unit in Marketing Cloud. Use only MIDs relevant to your connection.
Afterwards, use the incognito window to access the ‘Marketing Cloud’ tab again. This should reconnect your user using the correct token.

Comment: This is done, the connection has been working for quite some time.

Comment: Have you tried clearing user mappings and OAuth tokens?

Comment: I’m trying to understand how this issue is caused? The integration token is current. And the integration between MC and SC work fine. I’m not particularly keen on resetting the connection without an actual reason why.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is documented by Salesforce now:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318452&type=1&mode=1

> ## Salesforce Marketing Cloud Connect - Action Required to Prevent Service Interruption Email
>
> **Knowledge Article Number**  000318452
> **Description**      You may receive an email from the Marketing Cloud
> Connect managed package with the subject: "Salesforce Marketing Cloud
> Connect - Action Required to Prevent Service Interruption."
>
> This email would be sent if the package detects an issue when trying
> to connect your Salesforce org with your Marketing Cloud account
> through the Marketing Cloud Connect API User. Triggered sends created
> within the Marketing Cloud Connect managed package will be retried for
> 30 minutes before ultimately failing, unless the API User is
> re-integrated. Update your API user immediately to avoid interruption.
>
> **Resolution**     This email is deployed to any user marked as a "Marketing
> Cloud Connect for AppExchange Admin" in Salesforce or if your email
> address is used as the Support Ticket Recipient within the Marketing
> Cloud Connect managed package configuration screen.  This email is
> sent from any user in your Salesforce Org that performs an action that
> would then attempt to utilize the managed package API User
> credentials, but fails due to token issues.
>
> To avoid interruption of service with Marketing Cloud Connect,
> reconnect your Marketing Cloud Connect API User immediately as
> mentioned in the email received.  Below are the instructions provided
> along with a link to supporting help documentation.
>
> **Follow these steps to reconnect your API user**
> Log into your Sales or
> Service Cloud org as the Marketing Cloud Connect admin. Navigate to
> the Marketing Cloud tab. Re-enter your Marketing Cloud API user
> credentials.
>
> **Update Marketing Cloud API User Help Documentation**
> **If you continue to
> receive this email after following the above, please review the
> following:**
>  You will need to check your remote site setting
> OAuth_Login.  This remote site must exist and be in an active state.
> Once confirmed, you will want to reintegrate your API user using the
> ChangeAPIUser visualforce page (/apex/changeapiuser).  You can find
> this under Setup > Develop > Visualforce Pages > ChangeAPIUser >
> Preview In the October 2019 release, JSON Web Tokens were introduced
> as an improved way of authenticating that can reduce the likelihood
> that the API user will need to be reconnected. You can find more
> information in the release notes:
> https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_october_2019_mcc_jwt_compatibility.htm&type=5
>
> This error email will like occur due to Tenant-Specific OAuth
> Endpoints not being enabled within this MC Connector settings for your
> SF Org. When you enable Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints, it will clear
> your MC Configuration and prompt you to reconfigure/reintegrate. This
> will include going through the Automatic Setup Wizard, reconnecting
> the MC API user, and then setting up the MC Connector settings how it
> was prior to upgrading to TSE's. It may also prompt you to verify a
> new Remote Site Setting. If you are prompted to do so, please verify
> the new remote site. We also recommend taking a screenshot of the page
> prior to enablement, so you know how to use the same configuration
> settings. The path to your MC Connector Settings page is below:
>
> Login to your SF Org > ensure you are in Salesforce Classic > navigate
> to the Marketing Cloud tab > click "Configure Marketing Cloud
> Connector"
>
> After reaching the MC Connector settings page, you can enable
> "Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints" by scrolling to the bottom of the
> page to the "Advanced" section, and clicking the small arrow to expand
> the section. Finally, toggle "Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints" on.
>
> Once you have enabled Tenant-Specific OAuth Endpoints and
> re-established the Marketing Cloud API User's connection, this will
> enable the JSON Web Token (JWT) Authentication and should prevent this
> issue from re-occurring in the future."